# Is it possible to INSERT INTO and UPDATE the same row in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, logging, sql-update, sql-insert

Lets say I want to `INSERT INTO` a new row into `tLogs` with data from `tInput`. In the same query I want to `UPDATE` a column called `Action` in `tLogs` that does not exist from `tInput`. The example below illustrates:

```
____________tLOGS____________       _____tInput____
| id | pid | A | B | Action |       | pid | A | B |
|    |     |   |   |        |       |  1  | 0 | 0 |
```

The desired query would result in:

```
____________tLOGS____________       _____tInput____
| id | pid | A | B | Action |       | pid | A | B |
|  1 |  1  | 0 | 0 |  Add   |       |  1  | 0 | 0 |
```

In my actual application I have hundreds of columns, so realistically I cannot type each column out. I am looking for a generic command.

Is it possible to do both an INSERT INTO and an UPDATE in the same query? What would such a query look like?

Comment: You can't have dynamic columns in static SQL statements. The only option is to use VBA to create dynamically the Insert statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you need to do an `UPDATE`, just specify the new column's name and value directly/literally:

```
INSERT INTO tLOGS ( pid, A, B, Action )
SELECT pid, A, B, 'Add' FROM tInput
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, in my actual application I have hundreds of columns so I cannot manually type each one. The question has been updated.

Comment: @KangzeHuang If you were using an UPDATE statement you would still need to manually specify all of the columns. Please provide more information in your original question showing actual data instead of a simplification. That said, if your tables have hundreds of columns you probably have a bad database design that should be normalized.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a choice in this design (raw inputs). My actual data is exactly like this simplification, except with 200+ fields.

Comment: "I cannot type each column out". Well, somehow you have specify which values go to which fields. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was hoping there was a generic command to accomplish this, like specifying all fields plus this new field. If that is not possible, I guess I'll just have to manually type it all.

Comment: @KangzeHuang You can reflect-over column names in Access to build-up Dynamic SQL. Look up "Access INFORMATION_SCHEMA".